# Asyncio, Quart, ProxyBroker2

Tags: python, python-asyncio, quart, proxybroker

I am starter to python and at the moment I am trying to get free proxies from proxybroker2, but I keep getting error straight for 4 days. I am using Quart + asyncio + proxybroker2. As shown below, my code doesn't work, I keep getting variety of different errors, all of them are related to loop, even more some of that times the app just hangs and nothing happens.

```
import asyncio

from proxybroker import Broker
from quart import jsonify, Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('free_proxies', __name__)

broker = Broker()


@bp.route('/find_proxies', methods=['GET'])
async def find_proxies():
    try:
        # Call the find method asynchronously
        proxies = await asyncio.to_thread(
            broker.find,
            types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'],  # Modify the types as needed
            limit=10  # Modify the limit as needed
        )

        # Collect the results in a list
        all_proxies = []
        while True:
            proxy = await asyncio.to_thread(proxies.get)
            if proxy is None:
                break
            all_proxies.append({
                'host': proxy.host,
                'port': proxy.port,
                'type': proxy.schema,
                'anonymity': proxy.anon,
            })

        return jsonify(all_proxies)

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})
```

```
from quart import Quart

from free_proxies.routes import bp as free_proxies_bp

app = Quart(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(free_proxies_bp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).